# Javascript filter data array within array

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

This is my file

```js
const tabledata = 
  { 0: 
    { Id: 1
    , name: 'test1'
    , parameters: 
      [ { name: 'application_instance', value: 'home',              type: 'generic' } 
      , { name: 'application_name',     value: 'initial',           type: 'generic' } 
      , { name: 'application_role',     value: 'disk_init_role',    type: 'generic' } 
      , { name: 'customer_environment', value: 'development',       type: 'generic' } 
      , { name: 'customer_name',        value: 'guest',             type: 'generic' } 
    ] } 
  , 1: 
    { Id: 2
    , name: 'test2'
    , parameters: 
      [ { name: 'application_instance', value: 'home',              type: 'generic' } 
      , { name: 'application_name',     value: 'disk_init',         type: 'generic' } 
      , { name: 'application_role',     value: 'initial',           type: 'generic' } 
      , { name: 'customer_environment', value: 'development',       type: 'generic' } 
      , { name: 'customer_name',        value: 'guest',             type: 'generic' } 
    ] } 
  , 2:
    { Id: 3
    , name: 'test3'
    , parameters: 
      [ { name: 'application_instance', value: 'home',              type: 'generic' } 
      , { name: 'application_name',     value: 'initial',           type: 'generic' } 
      , { name: 'application_role',     value: 'initial',           type: 'generic' } 
      , { name: 'customer_environment', value: 'development',       type: 'generic' } 
      , { name: 'customer_name',        value: 'guest',             type: 'generic' } 
    ] } 
  , 3: 
    { Id: 4
    , name: 'test4'
    , parameters: 
      [ { name: 'application_instance', value: 'home',              type: 'generic' } 
      , { name: 'application_name',     value: 'initial',           type: 'generic' } 
      , { name: 'application_role',     value: 'disk_init_role',    type: 'generic' } 
      , { name: 'customer_environment', value: 'development',       type: 'generic' } 
      , { name: 'customer_name',        value: 'guest',             type: 'generic' } 
    ] } 
  , 5:
    { Id: 5
    , name: 'test5'
    , parameters: 
      [ { name: 'application_instance', value: 'home',              type: 'generic' } 
      , { name: 'application_name',     value: 'initial_disk_init', type: 'generic' } 
      , { name: 'application_role',     value: 'disk_initial',      type: 'generic' } 
      , { name: 'customer_environment', value: 'development',       type: 'generic' } 
      , { name: 'customer_name',        value: 'guest',             type: 'generic' } 
  ] } }
```

I need to filter all data that has `name` of `'application_role'` and a `value` of `'initial'`
I tried differnt filters but they al give the wrong outcome because in the application_name there is olso a value of initial and the filter add this to the outcome.

So the data need to be expliciet to:
`parameters[x].name  === 'application_role'`
`parameters[x].value === 'initial'`

Comment: This is not valid JSON

Comment: your `tabledata`  is not `data array within array`; it is  `data array within an object collection`. please clarify this point

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Array.prototype.filter` and `Array.prototype.some` for achieving your goal. Try this-

```js
var data={0:{Id:1,name:'test1',parameters:[{name:'application_instance',value:'home',type:'generic'},{name:'application_name',value:'initial',type:'generic'},{name:'application_role',value:'disk_init_role',type:'generic'},{name:'customer_environment',value:'development',type:'generic'},{name:'customer_name',value:'guest',type:'generic'}]},1:{Id:2,name:'test2',parameters:[{name:'application_instance',value:'home',type:'generic'},{name:'application_name',value:'disk_init',type:'generic'},{name:'application_role',value:'initial',type:'generic'},{name:'customer_environment',value:'development',type:'generic'},{name:'customer_name',value:'guest',type:'generic'}]},2:{Id:3,name:'test3',parameters:[{name:'application_instance',value:'home',type:'generic'},{name:'application_name',value:'initial',type:'generic'},{name:'application_role',value:'initial',type:'generic'},{name:'customer_environment',value:'development',type:'generic'},{name:'customer_name',value:'guest',type:'generic'}]},3:{Id:4,name:'test4',parameters:[{name:'application_instance',value:'home',type:'generic'},{name:'application_name',value:'initial',type:'generic'},{name:'application_role',value:'disk_init_role',type:'generic'},{name:'customer_environment',value:'development',type:'generic'},{name:'customer_name',value:'guest',type:'generic'}]},5:{Id:5,name:'test5',parameters:[{name:'application_instance',value:'home',type:'generic'},{name:'application_name',value:'initial_disk_init',type:'generic'},{name:'application_role',value:'disk_initial',type:'generic'},{name:'customer_environment',value:'development',type:'generic'},{name:'customer_name',value:'guest',type:'generic'}]}};


const res = Object.values(data).filter(
  item => item.parameters.some(param => param.name === 'application_role' && param.value === 'initial')
 );
console.log({...res});
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {min-height: 100%!important; top: 0}
```

Comment: You can't "correct" somebody's data structure -- what if that's how they receive it from the server?

Comment: on the original post tabledata is an object, not an array

Comment: I've updated my answer. But I believe the OP has done something like `data = {...[2, 3, 4]}`

Comment: the PO isalso asking for `application_role`, not `application_name` ...

Comment: Thanks, @MisterJojo. Updated the answer.